# CouchDB emit with lookup key that is array, such that order of array elements are ignored

Tags: couchdb

When indexing a couchdb view, you can emit an array as the key such as:
emit(["one", "two", "three"], doc);
I appreciate the fact that when searching the view, the order is important, but sometimes I would like the view to ignore it. I have thought of a couple of options.
1. By convention, just emit the contents in alphabetical order, and ensure that looking up uses the same convention.
2. Somehow hash in a manner that disregards the order, and emit/search based on that hash. (This is fairly easy, if you simply hash each one individually, "sum" the hashes, then mod.)
Note: I'm sure this may be covered somewhere in the authoritative guide, but I was unsuccessful in finding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the correct approach is to determine a conventional ordering on the keys, emit them in this ordering, and be sure to query with this ordering enforced. Otherwise we would need to emit all n(factorial) permutations of the keys (which could get bad if n is greater than 3)

Comment: Selecting this as the answer, will check back to see if anyone knows any couchdb features that would provide another way to do this.

Comment: This is also most appropriate because if you allow "unordered array elements" in your key you lose the ability to use group_level   http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views#Grouping

Answer (score 0):

CouchDB will always maintain the array keys in order. Have you considered emitting all sequence variations as part of the view? Something along the lines of:

```
function(doc) {
  function computeAllKeyVariations(fromKey) {
    // returns array of key arrays
  }
  var allKeys = computeAllKeyVariations(startingKey);
  for (k in allKeys) {
    emit(k, doc); // or emit(k, null)
  }
}
```

Side note: You also have the option to use `emit(['one','two','three'], null)` instead of emitting the document. This will avoid having CouchDB store the full document in the view index (more than once). To get the same results as before just make use of `&include_docs=true`

Comment: A concern with this approach is the size of the view.  The number of emitted fields is directly related to the size on disk, and the number of combinations will be (2^n)-1.

Comment: Actually, I'd hate to accept my own answer here, but it would actually be n(factorial). I want set identity, with disregard to the ordering, so I would need to emit each permutation. I think the correct answer here is just to construct an ordering, and consistently emit/query based on that convention. But to duluthian's credit, he might be thinking that I have a limited number of ways that I could represent the key orderings (like one or two different ways). That's not the case though, I need to support all orderings, so I like my answer :)

Comment: Fair enough. Though emitting the 6 permutations required by your example doesn't feel very expensive to me unless you expect the elements in your key to change on an extremely frequent basis.